# Ubuntu Live CD not so persistent (Unetbootin)

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, unetbootin

I have the following problem. I am trying to make Ubuntu Live USB (actually Lubuntu, but problem is the same with Ubuntu) with the persistency option. I use Unetbootin (both on Windows and Ubuntu problem is the same), set all options - and have working USB stick with Live CD. The problem is, even if I set preserved space to 1 Gb, I can't save any changes made on USB.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Unetbootin.png

My test is the following - I make USB stick with Live CD, I Try Ubuntu without installing, type command:

```
sudo adduser cheshire
```

fill all details, I have two folders in /home/ catalogue - ubuntu and cheshire. But after reboot I have again only /ubuntu/ catalogue. Actually I really need USB stick which will preserve this data - what I need the most is the openssh-server option.

Answer (score 0):

there is a program called etcher, for linux, windows, and osx. it seems to work really well for this job, although the options are limited.

[image: Etcher ui]